# Creating several DB instances from a single POST request

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table like this:

```
class Mapping(db.Model):
    map_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    bike_id = db.Column(db.String(255))
    is_active_data = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(150))
    updated_by = db.Column(db.String(150))
```

My **POST** method:

```
def save_MapperM(adddata):
    create_data = Mapping(**adddata)
    db.session.add(create_data)
    db.session.commit()
    return dict(Successful="Successfully Created")
```

**Route:**

```
@test.route("/addmapper"))
class MapperV(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            save_data = request.get_json()
            try:
                return jsonify(save_MapperM(save_data))
            except Exception:
                return jsonify({'Unsuccessful': 'Looks like you missed something !!'})
```

Current Code :

- The current code will take only one bike_id for every request.

Requirements:

- I want to take multiple bike_id's as for one user id and store it as multiple records in the table level.

Example data format coming from UI:

```
   { user_id: 1, bike_id: 1,2,3,4 }
```

Comment: Could you add your flask route function? How do you get request parameters and pass the to the `save_MapperM` function?

Comment: @SergeyShubin, Please check the updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to modify your `save_MapperM` function with a cycle:

```
def save_MapperM(adddata):
    for bike_id in adddata["bike_id"]:
        item_data = adddata.copy()
        item_data["bike_id"] = bike_id
        create_data = Mapping(**item_data)
        db.session.add(create_data)
    db.session.commit()
    return dict(Successful="Successfully Created")
```

But be careful with this function as it allows to create `Mapping` instances with any parameters received from the POST request. It looks like it is intended but it can lead to security issues if your `Mapping` class has some private attributes which should be filled only on the server side. For example the user "Mike" can send a request:

```
{ "user_id": 1, "bike_id": [1, 2], "created_by": "Alex", "updated_by": "Alex" }
```

It will cause the `save_MapperM` function to create instances with `created_by` and `updated_by` values set to "Alex" which may not be true. It is better to get such attributes from the [session data](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions).

So your post method may look like this (`post` and `save_MapperM` functionality combined):

```
def post():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    for bike_id in request_data.get("bike_id", []):
        item = Mapping(
            user_id=request_data.get("user_id"),
            bike_id=bike_id,
            created_by=session.get("username"),
            updated_by=session.get("username"),
        )
        db.session.add(item)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception:
        return jsonify({"success": False})
    return jsonify({"success": True})
```

The next step may be implementing request JSON data validation. It is OK when you have a couple of JSON keys with a simple structure but when you need to pass lots of data you need to be sure it is correct. You can use some of the serialization/ODM libraries for this [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for example.

Comment: @sukumarkumar It is the same `Mapping` class (SQLAlchemy model) as in your question.